# Bug on home page?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

The home page is blank for me. It is the same with meta. Anyone else with ideas/solutions/problems?
[image: bug]

Comment: It isn't for me, but PPCG is quite slow at the moment, which might be related.

Comment: @MartinBüttner A timeout when querying the database, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. We experienced numerous attempted DDoS attacks last week. I'm almost certain that this was the cause of your issues. Questions will not appear in the case that the time taken to load them is too long, which would happen under heavy (DDoS-like) load. You should not be experiencing this issue at this time, since we are not currently being DDoS'd. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin suggested, it's probably due to the site being slow. Even though it lags a bit, I can now fetch the list of questions occasionally (it takes a bunch of refreshes, though... still a bit of a problem).